# Trying to auto popolate form fields in django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, geocoding, geoip

i am trying to auto populate the latitude and longitude field in my forms
I am doing this thing in this way

```
     #forms.py 
        class registerForm(forms.ModelForm): 
            class Meta:
                model=register
                fields = ('Availability', 'Status')#'latitude','longitude',

            def save(self,ip_address, *args, **kwargs):
                g = GeoIP()
                lat, lon = g.lat_lon(ip_address)
                user_location = super(registerForm, self).save(commit=False)
                user_location.latitude = lat
                user_location.longitude = lon
                user_location.save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and my views have this thing

```
#views.py
    def status_set(request):
           if request.method == "POST":
        ip_address=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
            rform = registerForm(data = request.POST)
            if rform.is_valid():
                register = rform.save(commit=False)
                register.user=request.user
                register.save(ip_address)
                return render_to_response('home.html')
        else:
            rform = registerForm() 
        return render_to_response('status_set.html',{'rform':rform})
```

but when i try to submit the forms it says "save() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)"the error is here "         `register = rform.save(commit=False)"` i em unable to figure it out 
any help will be greatly appreciated em using django 1.1.1 and GeoIP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your `save` definition on your `registerForm` - you added `ipaddress` as an argument, but in your view you aren't passing it in. If you want to keep calling `save()` the way you are now, make `ipaddress=None` in your function definition, or some other default value that you can handle.

Comment: can yew please give me an example about how to pass an argument in views to forms

Comment: When you call rform.save(), pass in ipaddress - like so: `reg = rform.save(ipaddress=request.META.GET('REMOTE_ADDR'), commit=False)`

Comment: still the same error can i get any tutorial or documentation about passing the args and **kwargs or any toturial about how to pass the parameters to forms from views

Comment: Oh - my mistake. The issue is when you're calling `register.save(ip_address)` on your model - your form saving code is fine, but you need to take a look at your `register` model's `save()` method.